# Find $x$ such that $\cosh(a + bx) + 1 = cx$

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, hyperbolic-functions, transcendental-equations

> I need to find an analytical solution for $x$ to:
> $$
> \cosh(a + bx) + 1 = cx
> $$

where a,b and c are real parameters.

I have tried to tackle this geometrically, by splitting the problem into finding the intersection of two curves, one being $y=\cosh(a + bx) + 1$ and the other being $y = cx$, but with no luck.

I tried to convert to polar form but I cannot seem to convert $y = \cosh(a+bx)$ easily.

The solution I am looking for must be in the form $x = \dots$. Ideally $x$ should be real but I'm not too concerned if it turns out to be complex.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: You'll need to solve this numerically for given $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $ax+b=w$ to simplify the equation:

$\cosh(ax+b)+1=cx\iff \cosh(w)=\frac cbw-\frac{ac}b-1=uw+v$

We use [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) to get a real root:

$$\cosh(w)-uw=v\implies w=-\frac vu+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{u^nn!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\cosh^n(w)\right|_{-\frac vu}$$

Finally, applying binomial theorem or a Wolfram functions [identity](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cosh/20/02/0005/) gives:

$$\cosh(w)-uw=v\implies w=-\frac vu+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{(2m-n)^{n-1}e^{\frac vu(n-2m)}}{(2u)^n(n-m)!m!}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7BFindRoot%5Bcosh%28w%29-3.4w-0.6%2C%7Bw%2C0%7D%5D%2C-%280.6%2F3.4%29%2Bsum%5Bsum%5B%281%2F3.4%29%5En%2F%282%5En+m%21+%28n-m%29%21%29+%282m-n%29%5E%28n-1%29+e%5E%28%282m-n%29%28-0.6%2F3.4%29%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C30%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D%7D)

Comment: There may be an expression for the other root of the equation, but how would one find it?

Comment: Hi @Tyma Gaidash, thanks for this. I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am thinking how to get the other root.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: take $u=a+bx \ $ as a substitution
$$x=\frac{u-a}{b}\to \\
cosh(a+bx)+1=cx\\cosh(u)+1=c\frac{u-a}{b}\\e^u+e^{-u}+2=2c\frac{u-a}{b}$$

Comment: There is no analytic solution in terms of elementary functions (powers of x, sin, cos, $e^x$ and $ln(x)$).

Comment: I'm aware that there are methods to test whether a solution to an ODE has an elementary solution, but I'm not sure for static equations like this.  Could you explain how you know that, please .. that the solution is not elementary?

Answer (score 1):

I tried an approach using the Laplace transform which goes as follows. $cosh(a+bx):=\frac{e^{(a+bx)}+e^{-(a+bx)}}{2}=cx-1$. Now $e^{(a+bx)}+e^{-(a+bx)}=2cx-2$. Then taking the Laplace transform on both sides we get: $e^{a}×\frac{1}{s-b}+e^{-a}×\frac{1}{s+b}=2c[\frac{1}{s^{2}}]-2[\frac{1}{s}]$. We can rewrite: $\frac{e^{a}}{(s-b)}+\frac{e^{-a}}{(s+b)}=\frac{2c}{s^{2}}-\frac{2}{s}$. Now we simply do common denominators as follows: $\frac{e^{a}(s+b)+e^{-a}(s-b)}{(s^{2}-b^{2})}=\frac{2c-2s}{s^{2}}=2(\frac{c-s}{s^{2}})$. I don't know where it may lead, or if it is useful in itself, but I wanted to share it because someone can maybe take the idea and solve the problem using the Laplace transform.

Comment: Would taking the Laplace transform on both sides make the new equation have the same solution?

Comment: Good point.  When we have an equation, it makes sense to take the Laplace transform of both sides only if that equation holds for all values of $x$.